# How to get depth images from Kinect and SoftKinetic at the same time?

Tags: computer-vision, kinect, depth

I am trying to view the depth images from [Kinect for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/) and [SoftKinetic DepthSense 325](http://www.softkinetic.com/en-us/products/depthsensecameras.aspx) at the same time. Later, I plan to write a program to grab and write the depth images from both devices.

For viewing depth images from Kinect for Windows, I am using the `DepthBasics-D2D` program from the [Kinect SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindowsdev/start.aspx). For viewing depth images from SoftKinetic camera, I am using the `DepthSenseViewer` that ships with the driver.

I find that these two devices cannot be plugged in and used at the same time!

If I have SoftKinetic plugged in and DepthSenseViewer displaying the depth and then I plug in the Kinect, then the DepthBasics program reports that `no Kinect could be found`.

If I have Kinect plugged in and DepthBasics program display the depth and then I run the DepthSenseViewer and try to register the depth ndoe, it reports error: `couldn't start streaming (error 0x3704)`.

Why cannot I view depth images from both Kinect and SoftKinetic simultaneously? Is there a way I can grab depth images from both devices?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the two devices aren't trying to run on the same USB hub. To try to resolve the problem, you might try one device on a USB2 port and the other device on a USB3 port.

(Egad this is an old post. Anyway, it will still be helpful to someone.)